# Where does the software in the repositories come from?

Tags: software-center, repository

Where does the software in the main repositories come from?

By "main repositories" I mean the default repositories used when you install Ubuntu from a fresh ISO, and by this I also include all the disabled sources from the same origin, such as `universe`, `restricted`, and `multiverse`.

And by "come from", I mean is the available software chosen or voted on to ensure no one sneaks in any malware, or can anyone contribute to and get their library or software into the main repositories?